# How to do the modulus calculation without using mod funct in Python

Tags: python

I am coding in Python and using Putty, I couldnt find the right way to do a program that does a modulus calculation without the mod function.

```
def main()

    Input1 = int(input("Type in first number"))
    Input2 = int(input("Type in second number"))

    q = (input1 / Input2)   #finding quotient (integer part only)
    p = (q * Input2)    //finding product
    m = (Input1 - p)    //finding modulus
    print(Input1, "%", Input2, "=", m)
main
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the modulus operator: `%`, if that's what you mean by "mod function"?

Comment: Anyway, there are syntax errors in the code you posted, is that the problem? Or do you have code that doesn't have errors, but gives the wrong answer?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? If Python 3, using `/` is definitely wrong. You want `//` for floor division instead of floating point "true" division. Even in Py2, `//` works reliably, so you could use it anyway to avoid portability issues.

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your code. (eg `input1 -> Input1`, `// -> #`.) After fixing those, your code works with Integar.

Comment: What does this have to do with putty?

Comment: What is your *exact* problem? Because the provided code doesn't work, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():

    Input1 = int(input("Type in first number"))
    Input2 = int(input("Type in second number"))

    q = (Input1 / Input2)
    for i in range(0, Input1, Input2):
        if Input1 - i < Input2:
            print(Input1-i)
```

This is a way to find what x mod y is in any given circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

The following sequence of operations solve mod.

`n mod d = m`

> Example:
>
> 6 mod 8 = m

```
def mod(n,d):
                     # n  : numerator or dividend
                     # d  : denominator or divisor
   q = n / d         # q  : quotient as a float
   qw = int(q)       # qw : whole number    
   p = qw * d        # p  : product of     
   m = n - p         # m  : result of mod

   return m

print(mod(6,8))
```